# Link tables/rows in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

In my database I have 3 tables, one for customers, one for orders and one for products. A customer can have any number of orders and an order can have any number of products. How can I implement this relationship between the 3 tables?

Information stored in the database:

Customer: social security number, name, address, phone number

Order: order number, date

Product: product id, category, price

Comment: You need to use a foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Here's where to start.

First you need an ID for each table (an ID is a unique identifier, so that if i say want customer X, there won't be 2 customer X in the table)
For customer u can use social security number (or you create a column called `CUSTOMER_ID`)

A customer can have any number of orders, So you should put a column in order to know this order belongs to which customer. So in order you add a column called `CUSTOMER_ID` that references `CUSTOMER_ID` in the table `CUSTOMER`

so these 2 orders belong to CUSTOMER with CUSTOMER_ID = 1:

```
ORDER_NUMBER     DATE        CUSTOMER_ID
1                1/1/2013         1
2                2/1/2013         1
```

`CUSTOMER_ID` in `ORDERS` is called a `FOREIGN KEY`

The same goes for the rest.

(PS : change the name of the table `ORDER`, `ORDER` is a keyword used in SQL, to order the items `SELECT .... FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY ....`)